# updating and deleting items in sharepoint spfx

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, spfx

```
import { Version } from '@microsoft/sp-core-library';
import {
  IPropertyPaneConfiguration,
  PropertyPaneTextField
} from '@microsoft/sp-property-pane';
import { BaseClientSideWebPart } from '@microsoft/sp-webpart-base';
import { IReadonlyTheme } from '@microsoft/sp-component-base';
import {
  SPHttpClient,
  SPHttpClientResponse,
} from '@microsoft/sp-http';
import styles from './UplWebPart.module.scss';
import * as strings from 'UplWebPartStrings';

export interface IUplWebPartProps {
  description: string;
}

export interface SPList {
  value: SPListItem[];
}

export interface SPListItem {
  Title: string;
  field_0: string;
  field_2: string;
  field_3: string;
  field_4: string;
  Id: number; 
}

export default class UplWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IUplWebPartProps> {
  private _getListData(): Promise<SPList> {
    return this.context.spHttpClient.get(
      this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl +
        "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('list for sharepoint')/items",
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1
    ).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
      return response.json();
    });
  }

  private _updateListItem(itemId: number, title: string, field_0: string, field_2: string, field_3: string, field_4: string): Promise<void> {
    const itemEndpoint = `${this.context.pageContext.web.absoluteUrl}/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('list for sharepoint')/items(${itemId})`;

    const headers: HeadersInit = {
      'Accept': 'application/json;odata=nometadata',
      'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
      'odata-version': ''
    };

    const body: string = JSON.stringify({
      Title: title,
      field_0: field_0,
      field_2: field_2,
      field_3: field_3,
      field_4: field_4
    });

    return this.context.spHttpClient.post(itemEndpoint, SPHttpClient.configurations.v1, {
      headers: headers,
      body: body
    }).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {
      if (response.ok) {
        // Item updated successfully
        return Promise.resolve();
      } else {
        // Handle errors here if needed
        return Promise.reject("Failed to update item");
      }
    });
  }

  private _renderList(): void {
    this._getListData().then((response) => {
      let html: string = '<table border="1" width="100%" style="border-collapse:collapse;">';
      html += '<th>Last name</th><th>First name</th><th>Gender</th><th>Date Of Birth</th><th>Job Title</th><th>Actions</th>';
      response.value.forEach((item: SPListItem, index: number) => {
        html +=
          `<tr>
            <td>${item.Title}</td>
            <td>${item.field_0}</td>
            <td>${item.field_2}</td>
            <td>${item.field_3}</td>
            <td>${item.field_4}</td>
            <td>
              <button class="updateButton" data-id="${item.Id}">Update</button>
              <!-- Hidden edit form -->
              <div class="edit-form hidden" data-id="${item.Id}">
                <!-- Last Name -->
                <label for="editLastName">Last Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="editLastName" value="${item.Title}" /><br />

                <!-- First Name -->
                <label for="editFirstName">First Name:</label>
                <input type="text" id="editFirstName" value="${item.field_0}" /><br />

                <!-- Gender -->
                <label for="editGender">Gender:</label>
                <input type="text" id="editGender" value="${item.field_2}" /><br />

                <!-- Date of Birth -->
                <label for="editDateOfBirth">Date of Birth:</label>
                <input type="date" id="editDateOfBirth" value="${item.field_3}" /><br />

                <!-- Job Title -->
                <label for="editJobTitle">Job Title:</label>
                <input type="text" id="editJobTitle" value="${item.field_4}" /><br />

                <button class="saveButton">Save</button>
                <button class="cancelButton">Cancel</button>
              </div>
            </td>
          </tr>`;
      });
      html += '</table>';

      const listContainer = this.domElement.querySelector('#spListContainer');
      if (listContainer) {
        listContainer.innerHTML = html;

        // Add event listeners to the update buttons
        const updateButtons = listContainer.querySelectorAll('.updateButton');
        updateButtons.forEach((button) => {
          button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const itemId = button.getAttribute('data-id');
            const editForm = listContainer.querySelector(`.edit-form[data-id="${itemId}"]`);
            if (editForm) {
              editForm.classList.remove('hidden');
            }
          });
        });

        const saveButtons = listContainer.querySelectorAll('.saveButton');
        saveButtons.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        const itemId = button.getAttribute('data-id');

    // Check if itemId is not null
    if (itemId !== null) {
      const editForm = listContainer.querySelector(`.edit-form[data-id="${itemId}"]`);
      if (editForm) {
        const titleInput = editForm.querySelector('#editLastName') as HTMLInputElement;
        const field_0Input = editForm.querySelector('#editFirstName') as HTMLInputElement;
        const field_2Input = editForm.querySelector('#editGender') as HTMLInputElement;
        const field_3Input = editForm.querySelector('#editDateOfBirth') as HTMLInputElement;
        const field_4Input = editForm.querySelector('#editJobTitle') as HTMLInputElement;

        
        const title = titleInput!.value;
        const field_0 = field_0Input!.value;
        const field_2 = field_2Input!.value;
        const field_3 = field_3Input!.value;
        const field_4 = field_4Input!.value;

        this._updateListItem(parseInt(itemId), title, field_0, field_2, field_3, field_4)
          .then(() => {
            // Update successful, hide the edit form and refresh the list
            editForm.classList.add('hidden');
            this._renderList();
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            console.error(error);
          });
      }
    }
  });
});

        const cancelButtons = listContainer.querySelectorAll('.cancelButton');
        cancelButtons.forEach((button) => {
          button.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
            event.preventDefault();
            const itemId = button.getAttribute('data-id');
            const editForm = listContainer.querySelector(`.edit-form[data-id="${itemId}"]`);
            if (editForm) {
              editForm.classList.add('hidden');
            }
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }

  public render(): void {
    this.domElement.innerHTML =
      `<div class="${styles.upl}">
       <div id="spListContainer"></div>
      </div>`;

    this._renderList();
  }

  protected onInit(): Promise<void> {
    return this._getEnvironmentMessage().then(message => {
    });
  }

  private _getEnvironmentMessage(): Promise<string> {
    if (!!this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams) {
      return this.context.sdks.microsoftTeams.teamsJs.app.getContext()
        .then(context => {
          let environmentMessage: string = '';
          switch (context.app.host.name) {
            case 'Office':
              environmentMessage = this.context.isServedFromLocalhost ? strings.AppLocalEnvironmentOffice : strings.AppOfficeEnvironment;
              break;
            case 'Outlook':
              environmentMessage = this.context.isServedFromLocalhost ? strings.AppLocalEnvironmentOutlook : strings.AppOutlookEnvironment;
              break;
            case 'Teams':
              environmentMessage = this.context.isServedFromLocalhost ? strings.AppLocalEnvironmentTeams : strings.AppTeamsTabEnvironment;
              break;
            default:
              throw new Error('Unknown host');
          }

          return environmentMessage;
        });
    }

    return Promise.resolve(this.context.isServedFromLocalhost ? strings.AppLocalEnvironmentSharePoint : strings.AppSharePointEnvironment);
  }

  protected onThemeChanged(currentTheme: IReadonlyTheme | undefined): void {
    if (!currentTheme) {
      return;
    }

    const {
      semanticColors
    } = currentTheme;

    if (semanticColors) {
      this.domElement.style.setProperty('--bodyText', semanticColors.bodyText || null);
      this.domElement.style.setProperty('--link', semanticColors.link || null);
      this.domElement.style.setProperty('--linkHovered', semanticColors.linkHovered || null);
    }
  }

  protected get dataVersion(): Version {
    return Version.parse('1.0');
  }

  protected getPropertyPaneConfiguration(): IPropertyPaneConfiguration {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
}
```

i have written this code to be able to make an html table, i would like to be able to update and delete the items in my table through this same webpart, using either pnp or ajax library, any tips on how i could implement this code?

i have tried the code you see above but it says that my date format is wrong in the console

Answer (score 0):

This is a form I made before with additions, deletions, and modifications.

[image: here is list]
[image: Here is spfx webpart]
I have processed the date in the code, you can refer to my code and try to convert your date to a standard date format

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { IHelloWorldProps } from './IHelloWorldProps';
//import { escape } from '@microsoft/sp-lodash-subset';
import styles from './HelloWorld.module.scss';
import { DatePicker, IDatePickerStrings } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/DatePicker';
import { PeoplePicker, PrincipalType } from "@pnp/spfx-controls-react/lib/PeoplePicker";
import { TextField } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/TextField';
import { Label } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Label';
import { Web } from "@pnp/sp/presets/all";
import "@pnp/sp/lists";
import "@pnp/sp/items";
import { PrimaryButton } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Button';
import { VerticalDivider } from 'office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Divider';
import { ChoiceGroup, IChoiceGroupOption } from '@fluentui/react';




export interface IStates {
    Items: any;
    ID: any;
    EmployeeName: any;
    EmployeeNameId: any;
    HireDate: Date;
    JobDescription: any;
    HTML: any;
    //singleValueChoiceGroup: string;
    multiValueCheckbox: any;
    singleValueOptions: any;
    multiValueOptions: any;
    Test: any;
    Choices: [];
}



export default class CRUDReact extends React.Component<IHelloWorldProps, IStates> {
    constructor(props: IHelloWorldProps | Readonly<IHelloWorldProps>) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Items: [],
            EmployeeName: "",
            EmployeeNameId: 0,
            ID: 0,
            HireDate: null,
            JobDescription: "",
            HTML: [],
            //singleValueChoiceGroup: "",
            multiValueCheckbox: [],
            singleValueOptions: [],
            multiValueOptions: [],
            Test: "",
            Choices: []

        };
        this.onchange = this.onchange.bind(this);
    }

    public async componentDidMount() {
        await this.fetchData();
        var singleValue = await this.getCheckboxChoices("Test");
        this.setState({ singleValueOptions: singleValue });
    }

    public async fetchData() {
        console.log('fetchData');

        let web = Web(this.props.webURL);
        const items: any[] = await web.lists.getByTitle("EmployeeDetails").items.select("*", "EmployeeName/Title").expand("EmployeeName/ID").get();
        console.log(items);
        this.setState({ Items: items });
        let html = await this.getHTML(items);
        this.setState({ HTML: html });

    }
  
    public findData = (id: any): void => {
        //this.fetchData();
        var itemID = id;
        var allitems = this.state.Items;
        var allitemsLength = allitems.length;
        if (allitemsLength > 0) {
            for (var i = 0; i < allitemsLength; i++) {
                if (itemID == allitems[i].Id) {
                    this.setState({
                        ID: itemID,
                        EmployeeName: allitems[i].EmployeeName.Title,
                        EmployeeNameId: allitems[i].EmployeeNameId,
                        HireDate: new Date(allitems[i].HireDate),
                        JobDescription: allitems[i].JobDescription,
                        Test: allitems[i].Test
                    });
                }
            }
        }
        console.log(allitems)
        console.log('findfate');

    }

    public async getHTML(items: any[]) {
        var tabledata = <table >
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Employee Name</th>
                    <th>Hire Date</th>
                    <th>Job Description</th>
                    <th>Test</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                {items && items.map((item, i) => {
                    return [
                        <tr key={i} onClick={() => this.findData(item.ID)}>
                            <td>{item.EmployeeName.Title}</td>
                            <td>{item.HireDate}</td>
                            <td>{item.JobDescription}</td>
                            <td>{item.Test}</td>
                        </tr>
                    ];
                })}
            </tbody>

        </table>;
        return await tabledata;
    }
    public _getPeoplePickerItems = async (items: any[]) => {

        if (items.length > 0) {

            this.setState({ EmployeeName: items[0].text });
            this.setState({ EmployeeNameId: items[0].id });
        }
        else {
            //ID=0;
            this.setState({ EmployeeNameId: "" });
            this.setState({ EmployeeName: "" });
        }
        console.log(items)
    }
    public onchange(event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {

        this.setState({ JobDescription: event.target.value });

    }
    public async getCheckboxChoices(fieldname: string) {

        var singlevaluechoices: { key: any; text: any; }[] = [];
        let web = Web(this.props.webURL);
        await web.lists.getByTitle("EmployeeDetails").fields.getByInternalNameOrTitle(fieldname).select('Choices').get().then((field) => {
            console.log(field);
            for (var i = 0; i < (field as any)["Choices"].length; i++) {
                singlevaluechoices.push({
                    key: (field as any)["Choices"][i],
                    text: (field as any)["Choices"][i]
                });
            }

        });
        return singlevaluechoices;
    }


    public _onChange = async (ev: React.FormEvent<HTMLInputElement>, option: IChoiceGroupOption): Promise<void> => {
        console.log(option);
        this.setState({ Test: option.key });
    }



    private async SaveData() {
        // console.log(this.state.EmployeeNameId);
        console.log(this.state);

        let web = Web(this.props.webURL);


        await web.lists.getByTitle("EmployeeDetails").items.add({

            EmployeeNameId: this.state.EmployeeNameId,
            HireDate: this.state.HireDate,
            JobDescription: this.state.JobDescription,
            Test: this.state.Test

        });
        console.log(this.state);
        alert("Created Successfully");
        this.setState({ EmployeeName: "", HireDate: null, JobDescription: "" });
        this.fetchData();
    }
    private async UpdateData() {
        console.log('testaction');
        let web = Web(this.props.webURL);
        await web.lists.getByTitle("EmployeeDetails").items.getById(this.state.ID).update({

            EmployeeNameId: this.state.EmployeeNameId,
            HireDate: this.state.HireDate,
            JobDescription: this.state.JobDescription,
            Test: this.state.Test

        });
        console.log(this.state);
        alert("Updated Successfully");
        this.setState({ EmployeeName: "", HireDate: null, JobDescription: "" });
        this.fetchData();
    }
    private async DeleteData() {


        let web = Web(this.props.webURL);
        await web.lists.getByTitle("EmployeeDetails").items.getById(this.state.ID).delete();

        alert("Deleted Successfully");
        this.setState({ EmployeeName: "", HireDate: null, JobDescription: "" });
        this.fetchData();
    }

    public render(): React.ReactElement<IHelloWorldProps> {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>CRUD Operations With ReactJs</h1>
                {this.state.HTML}

                <div>
                    <form>
                        <div>
                            <Label>Employee Name</Label>
                            <PeoplePicker
                                context={this.props.context}
                                personSelectionLimit={1}
                                // defaultSelectedUsers={this.state.EmployeeName===""?[]:this.state.EmployeeName}
                                required={false}
                                onChange={this._getPeoplePickerItems}
                                defaultSelectedUsers={[this.state.EmployeeName ? this.state.EmployeeName : ""]}
                                showHiddenInUI={false}
                                principalTypes={[PrincipalType.User]}
                                resolveDelay={1000}
                                ensureUser={true}
                            />
                        </div>
                        <VerticalDivider></VerticalDivider>
                        <div>
                            <Label>Hire Date</Label>
                            <DatePicker allowTextInput={false} strings={DatePickerStrings} value={this.state.HireDate} onSelectDate={(e) => { this.setState({ HireDate: e }); }} ariaLabel="Select a date" formatDate={FormatDate} />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <Label>Job Description</Label>
                            <TextField value={this.state.JobDescription} multiline onChange={this.onchange} />
                        </div>
                        <div>
                            <Label>Single Select ChoiceGroup</Label>
                            <ChoiceGroup onChange={this._onChange} options={this.state.singleValueOptions} selectedKey={this.state.Test} />
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </div>
                <div className={styles.btngroup}>
                    <div><PrimaryButton text="Create" onClick={() => this.SaveData()} /></div>
                    <div><PrimaryButton text="Update" onClick={() => this.UpdateData()} /></div>
                    <div><PrimaryButton text="Delete" onClick={() => this.DeleteData()} /></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export const DatePickerStrings: IDatePickerStrings = {
    months: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    shortMonths: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'],
    days: ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
    shortDays: ['S', 'M', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'F', 'S'],
    goToToday: 'Go to today',
    prevMonthAriaLabel: 'Go to previous month',
    nextMonthAriaLabel: 'Go to next month',
    prevYearAriaLabel: 'Go to previous year',
    nextYearAriaLabel: 'Go to next year',
    invalidInputErrorMessage: 'Invalid date format.'
};
export const FormatDate = (date: Date): string => {
    console.log(date);
    //var date = new Date();
    var date1 = new Date(date.getTime());
    var year = date1.getFullYear();
    var month = (1 + date1.getMonth()).toString();
    month = month.length > 1 ? month : '0' + month;
    var day = date1.getDate().toString();
    day = day.length > 1 ? day : '0' + day;
    return month + '/' + day + '/' + year;
};
```